# Many to many naming conventions

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration, naming-conventions

What I've understand so far is that many to many table naming conventions for Laravel are:

`users & privileges = user_privilege`

But what is the case with more complex names like:

`attributes & composed_attributes = ?`

As you can see there is a underscore symbol in the second table.
Is that underscore in the way of Laravel recognizing the pivot by default?
Is `attribute_composed_attribute` going to work?
If so what is the proper name for the second table in order to work?

Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be `attribute_composed_attribute`.

> Name of the pivot table should consist of singular names of both tables, separated by undescore symbole and these names should be arranged in alphabetical order

http://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/